# Total internal reflection of sine wave vs smooth step function

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, reflection, refraction

If an electric field described by the function

$$f(t)= \begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\ t<0\\
 \sin(t)&\text{if}\  0\leq t\leq \frac\pi2\\
      \ 1&\text{if}\ t>\frac\pi2
\end{cases}$$
encounters a refractive boundary an an angle greater than the critical angle for a sinusoidal wave of the same wavelength $f(t) = sin(t)$, what happens? Does the “wave front” part of the field reflect? I know a sinusoidal wave will continue to reflect, but I’m pretty sure the static field $f(t) = 1$ will establish itself through the boundary eventually.

Comment: This is not a wave. There is no spatial variation so talking about a boundary is meaningless.

Comment: @nasu Maybe my equation is wrong? I mean to say when a static electric field is established, the front of it propagates at the speed of light. If the "rise time" of the field is equivalent to a similar sinusoidal wave which would be internally reflected, what happens?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you are asking, but I think [evanescent waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field) may be very related.  They might even be what you are looking for.

Comment: @CortAmmon thanks for the input. I am aware that evanescent waves form on the boundary when a sinusoidal wave is totally internally reflected. Perhaps my understanding is poor, but I think of an electromagnetic wave as an electric field oscillating about a value (zero). A static field would have a value of 1 or -1. When the field is first created (say I quickly add charge to a metal plate), the front of the field propagates away from the plate. I'm curious to know if this wave front can be refracted/reflected like a normal wave since it is a changing electric field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you surmise, most of the energy will reflect **and** the static field will eventually impose itself.

The trick is that not all of the energy is concentrated at one frequency.  You basically have a step function which has an infinitely wide spectrum, including a DC component.

Those low frequencies behave differently.  At the extreme end, they move electrons around to create the static field you refer to.  If you wanted to study it more, you could use Fourier transforms, or use Laplace transforms to study the transients.

Comment: Interesting. So even if the "rise" were sinusoidal (from 0 to pi/2) it would be inaccurate to call it a single frequency?

Comment: Correct.  If you wanted to calculate it, there's a law of fourier transforms that $F(xy) = Fx \star Fy$, where $\star$ is a convolution.  You can multiply your sin(t) term by a pulse from 0 to 1, and then multiply the DC term by a step function, then add those results together.